# FBAudienceNetwork v4.1.0 Build Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I tried to include `FBAudienceNetwork.framework` because i want to display banner/interstitial ad unit in my app. But my app gave me several errors.

**Error**

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIContext", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIFilter", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdBlurredImageView.o)
>        objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
>   "_kCIInputImageKey", referenced from:
>        ___65-[FBAdBlurredImageView sliceImage:withAspectRatioInfo:withBlock:]
>      _block_invoke42 in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdBlurredImageView.o)
>        +[FBAdUtility(FBAdViewUtility) blurImage:withRadius:]
>      in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EAGLContext", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
>   "_kCIContextWorkingColorSpace", referenced from:
>        +[FBAdUtility(FBAdViewUtility) blurImage:withRadius:]
>       in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
>   "_kCIInputScaleKey", referenced from:
>        ___65-[FBAdBlurredImageView sliceImage:withAspectRatioInfo:withBlock:]
>      _block_invoke42 in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdBlurredImageView.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CIImage", referenced from:
>        objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdBlurredImageView.o)
>        objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Framework**

```
- MediaPlayer
- CoreMedia
- SystemConfiguration
- CoreTelephony
- AVFoundation
- StoreKit
- CoreMotion
- AdSupport
- Foundation
- CoreGraphics
- UIKit
- libc++.dylib
- libz.dylib
```

**Setting**

```
Architecture              : $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)
Deployment Target         : 7.0
FBAudienceNetwork version : v4.1.0
```

Additionally,
Do I need to include Bolts.framework for using just Audience Network?
After including it, errors are gone.
So I wonder if Bolts.framework is needed.

(When I use `FBAudienceNetwork` v3.23, these error were not occurred)

Answer (score 6):

I found out the solution.

I just changed my project setting.

```
Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - Modules

: Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) => YES
```

I hope this will be helpful for developers to use facebook's audience network.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your FBAudienceNetwork v4.1.0 doesn't support armv7 architecture. If that library is static - use Lipo or another tool to create a library file (.a) which support this architecture too. If this library isn't static - just add armv7 in its project file (FBAudienceNetwork.xcodeProj > Build Settings > Architecture).